# Can't access encoded form data from context.Request.Form

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm building some custom middleware into my request pipeline which will generate JWT bearer token if the posted form data is valid (hooked into AspNetCore.Identity).

Based on Nate Barbettini's great tutorial here:
https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

I've hit an issue where the HttpContext accessible in new my middleware, throws exceptions trying to access context.Reqeust.Form["myfieldname"]

I'm using postman to post form data using:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I can debug my middleware and inspecting the context.Request.Form I see this:

```
Form = '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest)((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext)context).Request).Form' threw an exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException'
```

If I change to Content-Type: multipart/form-data, I see this error:

```
Form = '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest)((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext)context).Request).Form' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException'
```

Worth pointing out I'm using RC2 version of Core: 1.0.0-rc2-3002702
The Api works fine with all Http verbs, POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, I can post and get data no problem.

Can't see why this would be happening or maybe I'm missing some fundamental configuration? Current config is pretty much standard as out of the box from the VS 2015 templates.

Could this be an RC2 bug?